# using regex with awk to filter results on a timestamps

Tags: regex, bash, awk, timestamp, hour

I am using following script to filter records from a text file.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]";} /20001223705/ {print}' LogFile
```

The command separates records based on 24 hour timestamp value (hh:mm:ss) and list all which contain the string `20001223705`.

Is it possible to print only the records that fall between a time frame. lets say I want to print only records from `14:16:31` to `15:01:10`.

**Sample Text:**

```
14:15:40.659 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf   ] SIPIntf : DVC  : sip_msg_get_contact_urn : fail to get urn 0 

14:16:42.831 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf   ] SIPIntf : SUBS : Free (0xca7fcbe0), Page (0xca7fcbc0)
14:48:53.371 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf   ] SIPIntf : TRX  : [0xcc132b48] Message To Send.

15:02:06.368 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf   ] OPTIONS sips:2000470-1106@10.210.155.248:5061 SIP/2.0
```

**Expected output:**

```
14:16:42.831 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf   ] SIPIntf : SUBS : Free (0xca7fcbe0), Page (0xca7fcbc0)
14:48:53.371 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf   ] SIPIntf : TRX  : [0xcc132b48] Message To Send.
```

Comment: would be better if you add an example input and expected output

Comment: Sample text/expected output added. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sample input:

```
cat sample.log
4:15:40.659 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf ] SIPIntf : DVC : sip_msg_get_contact_urn : fail to get urn 0
14:16:42.831 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf ] SIPIntf : SUBS : Free (0xca7fcbe0), Page (0xca7fcbc0)
14:48:53.371 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf ] SIPIntf : TRX : [0xcc132b48] Message To Send.
15:02:06.368 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf ] OPTIONS sips:2000470-1106@10.210.155.248:5061 SIP/2.0
```

`awk` solution to compare timestamp with start and end time. Store the start and end time in variables `s` and `e` respectively.  and then check if its greated than start time and less than end time.

```
awk -v s="14:16:00.831" -v e="14:58:53.371" 's<=$1 && $1<=e' sample.log
14:16:42.831 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf ] SIPIntf : SUBS : Free (0xca7fcbe0), Page (0xca7fcbc0)
14:48:53.371 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf ] SIPIntf : TRX : [0xcc132b48] Message To Send.
```

Comment: Any idea how would I insert the suggestion in following awk command, gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\n^[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-3][0-9] [01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]";} /SIPIntf/ {print RT$0}' sample.log

Comment: I do not know, but why would you want to use your awk command?

Comment: Because I'm filtering results using above awk command and want to further filter using time stamp

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '/^14:16:42.831/;/^14:48:53.371/' file
or
awk '$0 >14 16 31 && $0 <15 01 10' file

    14:16:42.831 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf ] SIPIntf : SUBS : Free (0xca7fcbe0), Page (0xca7fcbc0)
    14:48:53.371 ( 3398: 3403) [SIPIntf ] SIPIntf : TRX : [0xcc132b48] Message To Send.
```